# JQuery Mobile Menu using "this" Selector Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, menu, jquery

I'm trying to build a really simple mobile menu but it's not working, and I think it's because I'm trying to use the "this" selector.  This seems like something so basic, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's the HTML:

```
  <div class="menu-toggle">+</div>
   <ul class="level0">
      <li>sample</li>
      <li>sample</li>
    </ul>
```

And here's the jquery:

```
  $('.menu-toggle').click(function () {

       $('this').siblings('ul.level0').toggle();

});
```

Any ideas? I'm using "this" and "siblings" because there are multiple instances of this on the page, all with the same classes.  This is coming from a CMS so I can't add IDs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That is because `$('this')` is supposed to be `$(this)`.

`this` is an object whose value depends on the context it is used in (and in this case it's wrapped inside a jQuery object so it can have access to jQuery's various methods).

See more about JavaScript's [**this**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword.

**[jsFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zGN3f/)**